# Input & Output Button

Tags: javascript, button, input, output, buttonclick

can someone please help? I have been struggling with this for hrs. Here is the code. I have to be able to type whatever name into the boxes click the display button to show what I typed, concatenate with a hello and say what I typed below then also be able to hit the clear button to clear everything as if refreshed   I also have to have call a function on my other page named display Hello Message.  I can only get it to display the hello and the first name and clear one thing. Here's what I have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  \
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript: Input & Output Assignment</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Name - Input & Output</h1>
    <div>
      <label for="firstNameInput"> First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstNameInput" placeholder="Enter a first name" />
      <label for="lastNameInput"> Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastNameInput" placeholder="Enter a last name" />
      <button onclick="displayHelloMessage()">Display</button> <button onclick="displayHelloMessage()">Clear</button>
    </div>
    <p id="helloNameOutput"></p>
    <script src="/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to include the script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
      function displayHelloMessage() {
        var fname = document.getElementById("firstNameInput").value
        var lname = document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value

        document.getElementById("helloNameOutput").innerHTML  = "Hello " + fname + " " + lname 
      }

      function clearMessage() {
        document.getElementById("helloNameOutput").innerHTML  = ""
      }
```

Add theese functions to your js file and change onClick on the clear button to clearMessage

Answer (score 0):

Since I do not know what is going on in your script.js I put some custom jQuery in the HTML-script-tag and removed the onclick functions one the buttons.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  \
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript: Input & Output Assignment</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello Name - Input & Output</h1>
    <div>
      <label for="firstNameInput"> First Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstNameInput" placeholder="Enter a first name" />
      <label for="lastNameInput"> Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="lastNameInput" placeholder="Enter a last name" />
      <button class="display">Display</button> <button class="clear">Clear</button>
    </div>
    <p id="helloNameOutput"></p>
    <script>
      $('.display').on('click', function() {
      var firstname = $('#firstNameInput').val();
      var lastname = $('#lastNameInput').val();
      
      $('#helloNameOutput').text('Hello ' + firstname + ' ' + lastname) })
      
      $('.clear').on('click', function() {
      $('#firstNameInput').val('');
      $('#lastNameInput').val('');
      $('#helloNameOutput').text('') })
      
      
        
      
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

nullify the inputs' values. for example if onclick event has been triggered for the clear button, the function that is called can nullify the inputs by doing this:

document.getElementById("firstNameInput").value = "";
document.getElementById("lastNameInput").value = "";

all is done through purely Javascript.